# Permissions to run .exe/bat file using asp.net in windows 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, batch-file, exe, file-permissions

I have an asp code as :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Response.Write("Windows Account which runs ASP.NET is: "
             + Environment.UserName);

        System.Diagnostics.Process process1 = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        process1.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = Request.MapPath("~/");
        process1.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process1.StartInfo.FileName = Request.MapPath("update.bat");
        process1.Start();
        process1.WaitForExit();
        Response.Write("Done");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Response.Write("Error" + ex.ToString());

    }
}
```

The test.bat content is :

```
"O:\Program Files\QlikView\Qv.exe" /r "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\AMLCM\Qv\Proj\Project1.qvw"
```

IIS configuration is set to

IIS admin service, "allow service to interact with desktop" is checked. application pool identity set to "ApplicationPoolIdentity"

DefaultapplicationPool has full control over the website
the update.bat is at the same folder with website

On the web.config I have put the code below :

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="hosein" password="apass" />
```

on the machine.config I have added the code below

```
<processModel autoConfig="true"  userName="hosein" password="apass" />
```

The cmd program is ruining on the back ground but it does not showing any thing

Comment: any error log in Windows "Event Viwer" > Windows Logs > Application ?